# How to bind this function to input focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following simplified function. Real usage removed. So, onfocus I expect the value of the textbox to be alerted.

I would like to keep the function definition separate from the usage.

```
new function ($)
{
    $.fn.setFocus = function ()
    {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
} (jQuery);
```

My current attempt is not working:

```
$('input[type=text]').focus(setFocus);
```

How can I get this to work? thanks.

Comment: If you want to use the closure you current have.. wrap 'text' in quotes see if that will work.. otherwise I would do something like I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setFocus` is probably not defined. You should refer to the function itself, in this case `$.fn.setFocus`.

```
$('input[type=text]').focus($.fn.setFocus);
```

Comment: thank you, works perfectly. i don't know why i didn't try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("input[type='text']").focus(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

[jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: thanks, but I would like to keep the function and binding separate as per my sample. I tried the quotes suggestion and still no joy

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
function setFocus() {
    alert($(this).val());
}

$("input[type='text']").focus(setFocus);
```

What you did by assigning setFocus to $.fn was create a plugin that would alert the contents of a selected element:

```
$("#foo").setFocus();
```

Supplying $.fn.setFocus to jQuery's focus call will technically work, but it has other effects that you likely don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks more like it tries to extend the jQuery ..

Could it be that you want

```
new function ($)
{
    $.fn.setFocus = function ()
    {
        return this.focus(function(){
           alert($(this).val());
        });
    }
} (jQuery);
```

and call it like this

```
$('input[type=text]').setFocus();
```